# Whether LAMP is a collection of tools or a single tool?

Tags: linux, lamp

I have now setup a webserver in my Ubuntu Server 12.04.

I know that LAMP- Linux Apache Mysql PHP

I have installed apache,mysql,php separately.
like this

```
apt-get install apache
apt-get install mysql
apt-get install php
```

if I install apache,mysql,php separately, can it be called as LAMP?

Or is there a single package named LAMP?

should i install such thing like this (if available)

```
apt-get install lamp
```

This confuses me a lot

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is not a specific product as such. Every installation with Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP is *a* LAMP stack.

The way you set it up is a way to set up a LAMP stack on Ubuntu. There is also a metapackage called `lamp-server`. This can be installed with `apt-get install lamp-server`, but as long as all the components are working together in your install, you should be OK.

Comment: does this lamp-server package installs apache,mysql,php in a single instance? what it does?

Comment: @Anbu: the term "meta package" implies it just does the same as the separate commands, it is a convenience to save wearing out your fingertips on your keyboard, nothing more.

Comment: yeah got it.
but the lamp-server's configs are stored in /opt directory. And the apache,mysql,php are stored in /etc directory. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

There is NOT such thing like "apt-get install lamp" because there is not such a product or software.
LAMP is just an acronym from Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP and you can only install all this products step-by-step as stand-alone software.

> if I install apache,mysql,php separately, can it be called as LAMP?

Sure, this is the only one way to get LAMP installed!

Take a look at [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) article please:

- To start off we will install Apache ...
- In this part we will install PHP 5 ...

and so long.